# Are there any Java client libraries for OpenSocial?

Tags: java, opensocial, apache-shindig

I'm looking for a java client library for OpenSocial. There is [opensocial-java-client at Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/opensocial-java-client/), but it seems inactive. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: OpenSocial itself seems to be pretty moribund, at least as a public API. Google seems to use it under the cover in Google+, though...

Comment: If you want to add social features to your own site/web application, I think there are much better choices. Take a look at the Open Graph protocol, I haven't yet: http://ogp.me/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [Apache Shindig](http://shindig.apache.org/) and [Apache Rave](http://rave.apache.org/), both Java based and based entirely on OpenSocial.

Comment: I know both. ;) Apache Rave is as an answer is redundant as it uses the Shindig code. But tell me, where is a Java client in Shindig? I didn't see one.

Comment: There was an initiative at the JCP to start a Social Java spec: http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=357 but unfortunately, it has been rejected..